# Boto S3: make file public

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am using the Boto3 library to grab the download link for a file in S3. Even after adding the `acl` for the file to `public-read`, I get an "access denied" response when hitting the file url returned from the `generate_presigned_post` response.

My boto code:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket='bucketname',
    Key='filename.csv',
    Fields={
        'acl': 'public-read'
    },
    ExpiresIn=3600)
```

How can I make this s3 file accessible for download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate a presigned-post, you create a unique url which can be used to **POST** (upload) a file to a s3-bucket.

If you want to fetch a file, you should make a **GET**-request.

If the bucket is *"public read"*, you don't need to generate any *presigned request*.

I have not tested this yet, but I guess this would do the trick in order to download  the file:

```
key = bucket.get_key('filename.csv')
key.get_contents_to_filename('local_filename.csv')
```

If you want to create a download link for someone else to use, generate a *presigned* **GET** *request*.

Comment: Thanks for your help!